# WiX Front End support

Tags: cms-integration

First, is it even possible to have WIX as Front end CMS with CiviCRM back end. For example, I have event page on WIX, and registration goes through APIs to CiviCRM. I *understand* that CiviCRM supports it... but does WIX?

Second, can anybody share the good/bad/ugly experience? There is some new "code" functionality https://www.wix.com/code/home but it doesn't look very promising.

We have awesome web designer who is an expert in WIX. And since it is hosted service, it scares me how much will it take to integrate with CiviCRM (I am most familiar with Drupal version of CiviCRM; but I doubt that it will make any difference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CiviCRM will need to be installed in Drupal, WordPress or Joomla so you can't install in on a Wix site.  However if you want to make event registrations available on your Wix site it looks like you should be able to do that - see [here](https://support.wix.com/en/article/guidelines-and-limitations-of-the-html-code-and-embed-a-site-elements). That suggests you can embed external forms in iFrames or access 3rd party web services using Wix Code.  Not tried it, but looks like it should be possible.  Would make a good blog post if you do it!